# Do I need to set up a column with just a few possible values as an index for tSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, indexing

I'm creating an SQL Server 2008 database that may contain millions of records and I was wondering if I need to define the following as indexes:

1. TINYINT column that may contain only 0 and 1?
2. TINYINT column that may contain only: 0, 5, and 6?

PS. Both of these columns will be used in the WHERE clause for selection.

Comment: Why not `BIT` for the `0,1` column? Might this be extended to more values later?

Comment: Good point. Thanks. I'll change that. Still, what about the indexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, an index on these columns alone basically will never be used.

But such low selectivity keys make great candidates for composite keys, placed as the leftmost column in the index. Eg.say the `TINYINT (0,1)` (why not use [`bit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177603.aspx) btw?) is the `deleted` column. You have frequent queries that predicate with `WHERE deleted=0 AND ...`. Adding this as the leftmost column in the clustered index very often the proper approach. Or if the predicate is, say, `WHERE name = '...' AND deleted=0` you should make a non-clustered `index on (deleted, name)`.

Another option is to use a [filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx): `create index .. on (name) where (deleted=0)` but this does not cover the case where you *are* interested in the `deleted=1`.

Same goes for a column with few distinct values like, say, a `type` column. Again, making it the leftmost key in composite indexes usually makes  a lot of sense.

Note though that if you add a low selectivity key as the leftmost key in an index and you do *not* specify this column in the predicate (eg. `WHERE name='...'` w/o adding any criteria for `deleted`) then the index cannot be used, only an index `on (name)` (or `on (name, ...)`) could be used, ie. where `name` is the leftmost key.

Why not make it righmost key? eg. `index on (name, deleted)`? Because there's usually no benefit, only if you want to enforce an unique constraint. With only 0 or 1 to choose from an `index on (name)` or an `index on (name, deleted)` basically offer the same performance (if they can be used). Placing the low selectivity key to the left enables some range scan scenarios (eg. `WHERE type=5`).

Answer (score 2):

That is not a good idea because the selectivity of the index will be low, and because of this instead of "speed up", it could be a drawback.

**An index's selectivity is better the fewer rows have the same value**

In some other cases even a full table scan could be more effective.

Let say: you have 1 million rows. Then the selectivity of the first index is:

(*Selectivity = distinct values / rows)*

```
2 / 1.000.000 = 0,000002
```

in the other case:

```
3 / 1.000.000 = 0,000003
```

**These values are very low!**

Or on a different way:

Estimated Selectivity Ratio = (TotalRows / Distinct values) / TotalRows * 100 = 1/Distinc values * 100.

In the first case it is 50% in the second it is 33%.

Sql server's optimizer do not use indexes which has this ratio bigger then 15%.

(My calculation a simple estimation, but you can find statistic info in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384%28v=sql.105%29.aspx))

Comment: Just from curiosity, what should selectivity be on a column to qualify as an index?

Comment: You can have an estimated Selectivity Ratio like: ((TotalRows / Distinc Values) / TotalRows) * 100. = 1 / Distinc values * 100. In the first case it is (1.000.000 / 2) / 1.000.000 * 100 = 50%. Sql Server's optimazier do not use indexes which has this ratio > 15%